# Model Callback for login and logout

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, model, callback

Essentially this comes down to is it possible to use a [Model Callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html) in CakePHP to hook in when you log in and out.

The aim of what I am trying to do is log every time a user logs in or out of the application.

I have a custom log stream set up to save to the database the appropriate values.

In my UsersController.php I have this:

```
public function login() {
    // Check if we have post data
    if( $this->request->is('post') ) {
        // Reset any user data hanging around
        $this->User->create();
        // Log our user in
        if( $this->Auth->login() ) {
            // Success, redirect with a message
            $this->Session->setFlash( 'You have successfully logged in' );
            $this->redirect( $this->Auth->loginRedirect );
        } else {
            // Failure, flash a message
            $this->Session->setFlash( 'Incorrect Username/Password' );
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty standard from what I can see.

I then am looking for something in the Model to hook into the Login and Logout actions to write to the database with this.

```
CakeLog::write( 'Notice', "$username has logged in." );
```

I am aware that I could do this another way however I was specifically asked to do this through a Model Callback.

Comment: Why `$this->User->create();`? You are not adding a new user here, only logging in! Therefore it would not set any user data anyway - only reading it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array). I assumed that as it reset the user id it wouldn't hurt and might avoid any complications. Thinking back now it's probably not doing anything useful. Sorry I am a bit new to CakePHP as you might guess. @mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `$this->Auth->loginRedirect` there is a method for it:

```
$this->Auth->redirectUrl()
```

As documented and displayed in the example: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

But besides that, you can simply create your model methods and call them from within login:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    $this->User->loggedInCallback($username);
}
```

You can put as much logic and logging into that method as you like.

No need to make it any more difficult.

Comment: In terms of your first point because of the way I am set up using $this->Auth->loginRedirect simply forces that it is always returning me to the index action. In a larger application I can see your point of using redirectUrl() 

Perhaps I am over thinking this and your solution is what I am looking for. Thanks!